# How to write a Batch Script that searches for filenames and copy them to folder

Tags: batch-file

I'm not programmer, and very beginner in batch files, I'm just designer and after more searches I didn't find any program or batch or anything help me.

- I have folder with 28000 files in it.
- 28000 files named from 1.pdf to 28000.pdf
- example: files 1.pdf, 205.pdf & 17856.pdf for one project, 2.pdf, 56.pdf & 5863.pdf for another project .. etc.
- I have a .txt files for each project files name.

now i need to search/find each project files and copy them to each project folder

Comment: How do you know what PDF files are associated with each project? I know you said that you have a text file for each project, but how are you keeping track of the PDF names? Comma-separated values? Newline-separated values? Some mathematical algorithm where you can extrapolate filename based on project number?

Comment: files names for each project in .txt each name in newline

Comment: Do you have some specific problem? Have you coded something that you can add to the question? Thanks

Comment: I need a batch or anyway to ---
search/find each project files by its names that added in .txt file for each project --- and after find each project files --- copy them to each project folder